# Implementation of MVC pattern with paintComponent method

Tags: java, design-patterns, mvc, swing

Could someone review my code, with respect to OOP, clean code and MVC pattern?

**Main app:**

```
public class Application
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            //test
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                runApplication();
            }
        });

    }

    public static void runApplication()
    {
        Model model = new Model();

        MainFrame view = new MainFrame(model);
        Controller controller = new Controller(view, model);

    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class Controller
{
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ToolsMenu.class);
    // private Color selectedColor = StaticStuff.getShapecolor();
    private MainFrame view;
    private Model model;

    private Shape drawShape;

    public Controller(MainFrame view, Model model)
    {
        this.view = view;
        this.model = model;

        this.view.getToolsMenu().addRectangleListener(new RectangleListener());
        this.view.getToolsMenu().addCircleListener(new CircleListener());
        this.view.getToolsMenu().addLineListener(new LineListener());
        this.view.getToolsMenu().addPencilListener(new PencilListener());
        this.view.getToolsMenu().addRubberListener(new RubberListener());
        this.view.getToolsMenu().addColorListener(new ColorListener());
        this.view.getToolsMenu().addFillClosedShapeListener(new FillClosedShapeListener());
        this.view.getDrawPanel().addDrawPanelMouseListener(new MouseListenerForDrawPanel());
        this.view.getDrawPanel().addDrawPanelMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListenerForDrawPanel());
    }

    class MouseMotionListenerForDrawPanel implements MouseMotionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
        {
            if (!(drawShape == null))
            {
                if (drawShape instanceof Pencil)
                {
                    ((Pencil) drawShape).addPoint(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                }
                else if (drawShape instanceof Rubber)
                {
                    ((Rubber) drawShape).addPoint(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
                }
                else
                {
                    drawShape.setX2(event.getX());
                    drawShape.setY2(event.getY());
                }
                view.getDrawPanel().setTmpShape(drawShape);
                view.getDrawPanel().repaint();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
        }

    }

    class MouseListenerForDrawPanel implements MouseListener
    {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }

        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }

        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
        {

        }

        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
        {
            drawShape = getTmpShape(e.getX(), e.getY(), 2, 2);
            view.getDrawPanel().setTmpShape(drawShape);
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if (!(drawShape == null))
            {
                drawShape.setX2(e.getX());
                drawShape.setY2(e.getY());

                List<Shape> shapes = view.getDrawPanel().getShapes();
                shapes.add(drawShape);
                view.getDrawPanel().setTmpShape(null);
                view.getDrawPanel().setShapes(shapes);
                drawShape = null;
                view.getDrawPanel().repaint();

            }
        }
    }

    class ColorListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            Color selectedColor = JColorChooser.showDialog(view, "Chose color:", StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
            StaticStuff.setShapeColor(selectedColor);
            view.getToolsMenu().setColor(selectedColor);
        }
    }

    class RectangleListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
        {
            StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.RECTANGLE);
        }
    }

    class CircleListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.CIRCLE);
        }
    }

    class LineListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.LINE);
        }
    }

    class PencilListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.PENICL);
        }
    }

    class RubberListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.RUBBER);
        }
    }

    class FillClosedShapeListener implements ActionListener
    {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.FILLCLOSEDSHAEP);
        }

    }

    private Shape getTmpShape(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
    {
        switch (StaticStuff.getShapeType())
        {
        case RECTANGLE:
            return new Rectangle(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
        case CIRCLE:
            return new Circle(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
        case PENICL:
            return new Pencil(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
        case LINE:
            return new Line(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
        case RUBBER:
            return new Rubber(x, y, x2, y2, Color.WHITE);
        default:
            break;
        }
        return drawShape;
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class StaticStuff
{
    private static ShapeEnum shapeType = ShapeEnum.RECTANGLE;
    private static Color shapeColor = Color.BLACK;

    public static ShapeEnum getShapeType()
    {
        return shapeType;
    }

    public static void setShapeType(ShapeEnum shapeType)
    {
        StaticStuff.shapeType = shapeType;
    }

    public static Color getShapeColor()
    {
        return shapeColor;
    }

    public static void setShapeColor(Color shapeColor)
    {
        StaticStuff.shapeColor = shapeColor;
    }
}
```

**Super class for each shape:**

```
    public abstract class Shape
    {
        private int x, y;
        private int x2, y2;
        private Color color;

        public Shape(int x, int y, int x2, int y2, Color c)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.x2 = x2;
            this.y2 = y2;
            color = c;
        }

        public abstract void render(Graphics g);

        public int calcWidth()
        {
            return x2 - x;
        }

        public int calcHeight()
        {
            return y2 - y;
        }

        public int getX()
        {
            return x;
        }

        public void setX(int x)
        {
            this.x = x;
        }

        public int getY()
        {
            return y;
        }

        public void setY(int y)
        {
            this.y = y;
        }

        public int getX2()
        {
            return x2;
        }

        public void setX2(int x2)
        {
            this.x2 = x2;
        }

        public in

t getY2()
    {
        return y2;
    }

    public void setY2(int y2)
    {
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public Color getColor()
    {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }

}
```

**View part:**

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame
{

    private TopMenu menuBar;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    private ToolsMenu toolsMenu;

    public MainFrame(Model model) throws HeadlessException
    {
        super("Paint Application");
        prepareFrame();

        initializeToolsMenuComponents();
        initializeTopMenuComponents();
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

        JPanel mainLayoutforApplication = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        mainLayoutforApplication.add(toolsMenu, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainLayoutforApplication.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        this.add(mainLayoutforApplication);

    }

    public void prepareFrame()
    {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initializeTopMenuComponents()
    {
        menuBar = new TopMenu();
        menuBar.setTopMenu();
        setJMenuBar(menuBar.getMenuBar());
    }

    public void initializeToolsMenuComponents()
    {
        toolsMenu = new ToolsMenu();
        toolsMenu.setTools();
    }

    public ToolsMenu getToolsMenu()
    {
        return toolsMenu;
    }

    public DrawPanel getDrawPanel()
    {
        return drawPanel;
    }
}
```

**DrawPanel:**

```
public class DrawPanel extends JPanel
{
    private List<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<>();
    private Shape demoShape;

    public DrawPanel()
    {
        setOpaque(true);
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }

    public void addDrawPanelMouseListener(MouseListener listenForMouse)
    {
        this.addMouseListener(listenForMouse);
    }

    public void addDrawPanelMouseMotionListener(MouseMotionListener listenForMouse)
    {
        this.addMouseMotionListener(listenForMouse);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        for (Shape s : shapes)
        {
            if (s != null)
                s.render(g);
        }

        if (demoShape != null)
            demoShape.render(g);
    }

    public List<Shape> getShapes()
    {
        return shapes;
    }

    public void setShapes(List<Shape> shapes)
    {
        this.shapes = shapes;
    }

    public Shape getTmpShape()
    {
        return demoShape;
    }

    public void setTmpShape(Shape tmpShape)
    {
        this.demoShape = tmpShape;
    }

}
```

**ToolsMenu:**

```
public class ToolsMenu extends JPanel
{

    private JButton colorButton, rectangleButton, circleButton, pencilButton, lineButton, rubberButton,
            fillClosedShapeButton;
    private JLabel tipText;

    public ToolsMenu()
    {
    }

    public void setTools()
    {
        int numberOfColumns = 1; // = 0 many columns as necessary
        int numberOfRows = 0; // 0 = many rows as necessary
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(numberOfRows, numberOfColumns));

        tipText = new JLabel("Color Chooser: ");
        rectangleButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/tools/rectangle.png"));
        circleButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/tools/circle.png"));
        pencilButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/tools/pencil.png"));
        lineButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/tools/line.png"));
        rubberButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/tools/rubber.png"));
        fillClosedShapeButton = new JButton(new ImageIcon("images/tools/fill.png"));

        colorButton = new JButton();
        colorButton.setForeground(StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
        colorButton.setBackground(StaticStuff.getShapeColor());

        this.add(circleButton);
        this.add(rectangleButton);
        this.add(pencilButton);
        this.add(lineButton);
        this.add(rubberButton);
        this.add(fillClosedShapeButton);
        this.add(tipText);
        this.add(colorButton);
    }

    public void addColorListener(ActionListener listenForColorButton)
    {
        colorButton.addActionListener(listenForColorButton);
    }

    public void addRectangleListener(ActionListener listenForRectangleButton)
    {
        rectangleButton.addActionListener(listenForRectangleButton);
    }

    public void addCircleListener(ActionListener listenForCircleButton)
    {
        circleButton.addActionListener(listenForCircleButton);
    }

    public void addLineListener(ActionListener listenForLineButton)
    {
        lineButton.addActionListener(listenForLineButton);
    }

    public void addPencilListener(ActionListener listenForPencilButton)
    {
        pencilButton.addActionListener(listenForPencilButton);
    }

    public void addRubberListener(ActionListener listenForRubberButton)
    {
        rubberButton.addActionListener(listenForRubberButton);
    }

    public void addFillClosedShapeListener(ActionListener listenForFillClosedShapeButton)
    {
        fillClosedShapeButton.addActionListener(listenForFillClosedShapeButton);
    }

    public void setColor(Color color)
    {
        colorButton.setForeground(color);
        colorButton.setBackground(color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addRectangleListener(new RectangleListener());
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addCircleListener(new CircleListener());
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addLineListener(new LineListener());
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addPencilListener(new PencilListener());
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addRubberListener(new RubberListener());
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addColorListener(new ColorListener());
    this.view.getToolsMenu().addFillClosedShapeListener(new FillClosedShapeListener());
```

Use a temporary variable, this increases the readability.

---

```
            if (drawShape instanceof Pencil)
            {
                ((Pencil) drawShape).addPoint(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            }
            else if (drawShape instanceof Rubber)
            {
                ((Rubber) drawShape).addPoint(new Point(event.getX(), event.getY()));
            }
```

This seems like a place where you would have to add new functionality all the time.
Is there any way you could implement a strategy pattern here?

---

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {

    }
```

If your methods are empty, don't give them so much space. Put them on 1 line per method. Don't put space between them. Ideally, put a comment above them why they are there ("required to implement from `MouseListener` but unneeded").

---

```
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.PENICL);
```

Typo?

---

```
class RectangleListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.RECTANGLE);
    }
}

class CircleListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.CIRCLE);
    }
}

class LineListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.LINE);
    }
}

class PencilListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.PENICL);
    }
}

class RubberListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.RUBBER);
    }
}

class FillClosedShapeListener implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
    {
        StaticStuff.setShapeType(ShapeEnum.FILLCLOSEDSHAEP);
    }

}
```

Make 1 class. Call it ShapeListener. Give it a ShapeEnum. There, you've just saved tons of code duplication. Also... `FILLCLOSEDSHAEP` typo?

---

```
private Shape getTmpShape(int x, int y, int x2, int y2)
{
    switch (StaticStuff.getShapeType())
    {
    case RECTANGLE:
        return new Rectangle(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
    case CIRCLE:
        return new Circle(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
    case PENICL:
        return new Pencil(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
    case LINE:
        return new Line(x, y, x2, y2, StaticStuff.getShapeColor());
    case RUBBER:
        return new Rubber(x, y, x2, y2, Color.WHITE);
    default:
        break;
    }
    return drawShape;
}
```

Personally, I would add this method in `ShapeEnum`. Doing so would group related changes together (if you have to add a new shape, all you want to be editing is your shapes class/enum).

---

```
    public in

t getY2()
{
    return y2;
}
```

Looks like something went wrong here.

---

That's what I pulled from it after a single passthrough. I don't have comments on your design yet. Possibly because nothing really looked badly out of place and there were more issues in the code than in the design.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't get two parts of your comments with class "ShapeListener" and "ShapeEnum". Could you provide some details, what do you mean? Now i have something like this: pastebin.com/7g5ZwiCr This is my class responsible for keep color and shape choose by user. So should i refactor only adding action listeners to buttons part? And FILLCLOSEDSHAEP is not a typo, i have buttons for 5 shapes and 6th button is for filling the closed shape with selected color using the flood fill algorithm.

Comment: You spell shape like shaep?

Comment: I'd make 1 class called ShapeListener which has a constructor that takes ShapeEnum as argument. On ActionPerformed, it sets the StaticStuff.setShapeType to the ShapeType passed in during the constructor.

Comment: Ok now i get it :) thank you very much. My mistake it should be shape. Thanks!